# how to change the pipeline name in data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have created pipeline in data factory I want to changer the pipeline name but when i change this in pipeline i am getting error can you please help me?

```
"name": "TEST_debt",
    "properties": {
        "description": "Luna_debt",
        "activities": [
            {
                "type": "Copy",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "RelationalSource",
                        "query": "select * from `orbitms_live`.`debt`"
                    },
```

I want to change the name debt to Lunadebt

Comment: Since this is the first result when searching for "data factory rename pipeline", I'm providing a solution for 2020.

Answer (score 11):

You cannot change the name of the pipeline by editing the code, but by clicking on the "Properties" button you can rename this pipeline. [image]

Answer (score 4):

The simply answer is, you can't perform a rename operation at a pipeline level.

But...

If you want to change it in the Azure portal you can **Clone** the pipeline from the **Author and Deploy** blade. Then deploy the pipeline again with the new name and drop the old version.

Or...

Use Visual Studio. Again, it won't rename the pipeline. At publish time it will detect the difference and give you the option to drop the old version and create the newly named pipeline.

In both cases I would recommend you **Pause** the pipeline via the **Monitor and Manage** area to avoid duplicate data (depending on your activities).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't know if this was the case in 2017 but in 2020 you can rename a pipeline by editing the properties, see my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Navigate to your pipeline. It will be a URL like:

```
https://dev.azure.com/ORGANIZATIONNAME/PROJECTNAME/_build?definitionId=ID
```

Replace the tail of the URL, changing it from:

```
_build?definitionId=ID
```

to:

```
_apps/hub/ms.vss-ciworkflow.build-ci-hub?_a=edit-build-definition&id=ID
```

This is the page that appears when finishing editing a build. I assume there is a reason they didn't simply wire this page to a properties button; so use with caution. For example, although this works on the surface, it might disconnect something in the history, etc.